# Could you give me some advices to start coding joomla addons by using joomla framework?

Tags: frameworks, joomla

I know php but I need to write a joomla addon by using joomla framework. Could you give me some good advices to start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by reading the official documentation : [Creating a simple module](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_simple_module) or if you're using Joomla 1.5 : [Creating a Hello World Module for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5)

You can browse the [Developers Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) for all topics related to Joomla development.